# Tableau Public: What is the right way to create Calculated Fields?

Tags: tableau-api

I am learning Tableau Public. Using version 2020.02.02 MAC version
MWE ; Trying to create a new Calculated Field.

- use Samplestore dataset.
- In Data Source, drag the Orders table to Canvas.
- In Workspace, drag Profit dimension to Columns Shelf, and Categories measure to Rows shelf.
- In Data Pane, right click > Create > Calculated Field.
- In text field input 'PositiveProfit'.
- In text Area input expression:

  IF [Profit] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

I expect when profit is greater than 0, the value of this new calculated field should be 1. right?
Well I am getting something else. for example for Profit 18,451, PositiveProfit is 1,374.

What is the secret behind this? Any tutorials that explain?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your calculated field is being aggregated.  There are several ways to get around this.

**Method 1**

The easiest would be to click on PositiveProfit in the shelf and use the drop down menu to change it from Measure to Attribute.

**Method 2**

Another approach is to FIX PositiveProfit to your dimension.  Fixed calculations are also known as [Level Of Detail](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_fixed.htm), or LoD calculations.

So, in your case, it sounds like you want 0 or 1 for each Category. That means you should fix your PositiveProfit to Category.  So, create a new calculated field called PositiveProfitFixed:

```
{FIXED [Category] : MIN([PositiveProfit])}
```

And then place this new calculated field on the Columns shelf instead of PositiveProfit.
Note:  I'm using `MIN` but you could also use `MAX`.  Both will return the same result because the formula will return either 0 or 1 and the min of 1 is 1 and the max of 1 is 1 (and same is true for 0).

**Conclusion**

The first approach I mentioned above is by far clearer than the second approach.  And then are many other ways in which this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your formula.

Actually you have calculated that how many times the profit was positive.  See this screenshot

[image]

It may be clear that Profit `$18,451` is sum of all profit values of all rows with category `Furniture`.  There were `2,121` such rows (records).  Out of these 2,121 records,  `1,374` were the cases where profit recorded was positive and remaining cases were negative and thus, pertained to losses.

If instead you just want to calculate a field that just records that the profit you are showing is positive or negative, use this formula-

```
IF sum([Profit]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This will give you an output like this

[image]

Or if you'll change the hierarchy in rows, then

[image]

Thus to sum it up, this is not a proper use case of `LOD` in tabbleau.  However, you should know when to aggregate and when not.

P.S.  In tableau you can automatically sort profit values and can create a chart like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula to:

```
SUM([Profit])>0
```

This is a [boolean formula](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-boolean-data-type/), so will return True or False. If you need this to return 1 instead (perhaps you want to do another calculation on that, for example), wrap that formula in INT, where it will convert True to 1 and False to 0.

```
INT(SUM([Profit])>0)
```